# Are stack float array ops faster than heap float ops on modern x86 systems?

Tags: c, arrays, performance, floating-point

On C float (or double) arrays small enough to fit in L1 or L2 cache (about 16k), and whos size I know at compile time, is there generally a speed benefit to define them within the function they are used in, so they are stack variables? If so is it a large difference? I know that in the old days heap variables were much slower than stack ones, but nowadays with the far more complicated structure of cpu addressing and cache, I don't know if this is true.

I need to do repeated runs of floating point math over these arrays in 'chunks', over and over again over the same arrays (about 1000 times), and I wonder if I should define them locally. I imagine keeping them in the closest / fastest locations will allow me to iterate over them repeatedly much faster but I dont understand the implications of caching in this scenario. Perhaps the compiler or cpu is clever enough to realize what I am doing and make these data arrays highly local on the hardware during the inner processing loops without my intervention, and perhaps it does a better job than I can at this.

Maybe I risk running out of stack space if I load large arrays in this way? Or is stack space not hugely limited on modern systems? The array size can be defined at compile time and I only need one array, and one CPU as I need to stick to a single thread for this work.

Comment: Have you actually profiled your code and identified a performance problem, or is this just speculative, i.e. premature optimisation ?

Comment: There's no difference in the perf of the ops. From the processors point of view, memory is memory. Stack or heap, there's no difference. The benefit of the stack is that it is efficiently cached and allocation/deallocation is cheap.

Comment: Typical stack size is in the Mb range (1-8 Mb) in contemporary systems.

Comment: Speculative at the mo. I've timed execution of test programs to see roughly how expensive the operations are - not that expensive but this is to run on low power equipment like atoms. In reality the majority of my problems will be caused by os latency when I hand the cpu back to the OS between cycles but optimizing that is a different job to be tackled in the future. Right now the quicker I can make my processing cycles the quicker I will be able to catch up when my process has the cpu again. These operations are certainly the most expensive of my app by orders.

Comment: Cache efficiency is I guess essentially what I am asking about. To clarify when I defined 16k above, I meant my arrays are 16kb. So I want them kept in the fastest possible memory, which I believe is cache, but of course there are levels of cache. So if I can encourage the compiler / cpu to keep my data in the very top level of cache I win. If defining on the stack achieves this, I guess thats my answer, but if the compiler / cpu is far cleverer than me in this regard, and will cache what it detects it needs to optimize execution, stack or heap, then I guess I malloc?

Comment: Allocation is not a problem btw - I reuse the array continually, writing it out to hardware before reading a new set of data in to it from hardware, before processing, and cycling over (its for low latency audio processing). But I want to tell the compiler / cpu that this is the heart of execution, on which virtually all operations will occur, and of course they are expensive flops. Theres no need to malloc, change size, or anything - its a fixed size buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the allocation and deallocation speed that may make difference.

Allocating on the stack is just subtracting the required size from the stack pointer, which is normally done for all local variables once upon function entry anyway, so it is essentially free (unless `alloca` is used). Same applies to deallocating memory on the stack.

Allocating on the heap requires calling `malloc` or `new` which ends up executing an order of magnitude more instructions. Same applies to `free` and `delete`.

There should be no difference in the speed of access to the arrays once they were allocated. However, the stack could more likely be in the CPU cache already because previous function calls already used the same stack memory region for local variables.

If your architecture employs [Non-uniform memory access (NUMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) there can be difference in access speed to different memory regions when your thread gets re-scheduled to run on a different CPU from the one that originally allocated memory.

For in-depth treatment of the subject have a read of [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).

Comment: Regarding 'the stack could more likely be in the CPU cache already' - I think this might be the nub of my question. That said, I sequentially read into the array, before directly going to loops which process the array. So maybe this means either way, the cache will contain the array (always), and as long as I am not swapped out during my loops, it will definitely stay there for long enough for me to process it. Once written out after the loops, I have no need for it so flushing it to non cache memory is redundant and wasteful, albeit probably inconsequential.

Comment: @Pete You would probably need to benchmark to tell whether there is a significant difference for your workload.

Comment: ok thanks, if its that close that I need to benchmark it I can do that, I just wondered if there was a large obvious difference.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: probably not.

1. On a modern processor such as the i7 the L1/L2/L3 cache sizes are 64K/1MB/8MB, shared across 4x2 cores. Your numbers are a bit off.
2. The biggest thing to worry about is parallelism. If you can get all 8 cores running 100% that's a good start.
3. There is no difference between heap and stack memory, it's just memory. Heap allocation is way slower than stack allocation, but hopefully you don't do much of that.
4. Cache coherency matters. Cache prefetching matters. The order of accessing things in memory matters. Good reading here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/08/24/what-you-need-to-know-about-prefetching.
5. But all this is useless until you can benchmark. You can't improve what you can't measure.

---

Re comment: there is nothing special about stack memory. The thing that usually does matter is keeping all your data close together. If you access local variables a lot then allocating arrays next to them on the stack might work. If you have several blocks of heap memory then subdividing a single allocation might work better than separate allocations. You'll only know if you read the generated code and benchmark.

Comment: The 16k is my data requirement, not the cpu cache, but - since this is intended to run on low power hardware, I won't have the i7 kind of level of cache to play with. That said its probably in the hundreds of k typically. Because of the type of processing, I can't use parallel, or at least if I could the complexity of that is too much for me right now (it might well be, and seems to be currently, impossible right now). But as I commented above, I want to force my data to be kept in the fastest cache during processing, and until being written to IO hardware.

Comment: So from the comments and answers so far, the question really comes down to does allocating on the stack create a higher chance of being cached at the top level, and held there?

Comment: If you have more info, best to edit your question so everyone sees it. See edit.

Comment: David - will do. Was not sure whether to edit question or not.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same speed on average. Assuming the cache lines that the array occupies have not been touched by other code.

One thing to make sure is that the array memory alignment is at least 32 bit or 64bit aligned (for float and double respectively) so an array element will not cross cache line boundaries. Cache lines are 64 byte on x86.

Another important element is to make sure the compiler is using SSE instructions for scalar floating point operations. This should be the default for modern compilers. The legacy floating point (a.k.a 387 with 80 bit register stack) is much slower and harder to optimize.

If this memory is frequently allocated and released, try to reduce calls to malloc/free by allocating it in a pool, globally or on the stack.

Comment: The arrays will probably be 64 bit so I guess thats not a problem?